# Plot-Explanation to Equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

Something I did not understand while watching Equilibrium: They wanted to use prozium for cancelling out all (heavy) emotions for preventing a new war. But I can start a war even without having emotions (and this war is getting even better for me, because my soldiers aren't frightened anymore, they simply do what the officers tell them, even if they will be slaughtered). So, in my opinion that was not a good reason for using prozium. Am I wrong, or was there another purpose of using prozium onto the civilians (not onto the high-ranking personell)? Controlling?

Comment: It was designed more to eliminate the MOTIVE for war, rather than the action of war itself. Basically, it prevented war by taking away a reason to have war.

Answer (score 9):

**You're right.** It's not necessarily a good incentive or promise/reason for using Prozium, but once you do and win,...

The movie ist set in a post-apocalyptic/post-nuclear-war scenario, so it's very likely there's been little to no opposition left, simply due to the fact everyone left banded together (at least as far as depicted in the movie; ignoring the resistance).

If you've got only one state or society, there's no need for a military. In fact, there's no direct military in the movie. All that's left are the clerics, which act like a militarized police force fighting the resistance (and essentially any crime that's still happening).

If you consider all crimes you can think of, they're indeed based on some kind - or mix - of emotions. Greed, envy, megalomania,... It's the same thing that corrupted "Father".

The scenario you describe, having soldiers with no emotions, is the status quo within the clerics (and society in general). They're destroying works of art, killing resistance members, and slaughtering the dogs in one scene, without questioning their orders.

Having two or more parties fight over something would once again be the product of at least some kind of emotion. It's not explained how exactly obviously everyone accepted the concept of using Pronzium.

I could indeed even consider a scenario following your thoughts: The army without emotions is far more powerful than any opposition, so even if just one country, state, faction, or party would have used it to win against their opposition, the winner could create a whole society based on that "no emotions" doctrine, which would then become the society that's depicted in the movie.

Comment: But why then use prozium on the whole civilians? To prevent crimes? You will never get psychopats who just randomly kill people without any emotions...

Comment: Prevent crimes and opposition (*"I don't **like** that new agenda!"* and such).

Comment: Mario is right, and I wish I was awake 11 hours ago to beat him to the answer. It is established by the writer and the director in the commentary that the regime is only a few decades old at most, within Christian Bale's character's lifetime, and that it was always intended by the leadership as simply the best method of eliminating opposition, rather than to actually prevent war (since the war ended with one universal world government, there are no other states to fight). This is illustrated when "Father" shows emotion himself; if the drug was to prevent war, the leadership would take it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a circular logic here. You say: "But I can start a war even without having emotions (and this war is getting even better for me, because my soldiers aren't frightened anymore, they simply do what the officers tell them, even if they will be slaughtered)."
Yes, you can start it, but that would imply you need to get emotional to do so. In that society, there is no need for war (there is nothing to point to that) so the only conflict that could start would be based on someone having an emotional problem with someone else.
Soldiers that aren't frightened anymore can be ordered by an emotive commander to attack something, but that commander would need the emotional trigger to order so. Otherwise it would have no reason to give such an order.

The logic of prozium was that if you remove emotions you do not feel the impulse to attack anyone. And since there is no other reason for a war, none should happen. Unfortunately, as in most cases, it's the leaders themselves that are the first  not to respect the rules, therefore the interesting things happening near the end of the movie.

Prozium was being used not for a direct control (like mind control or something similar), but for emotion management - specifically the control of aggressive impulses.